# Is angular 4 auth guards server sided or client sided? If it is client sided can it be hacked?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-router, angular2-routing, auth-guard

I am currently working on angular 4 on a project. I'm familiar with angular auth-guards. My question is since angular 4 is a client sided framework can't we hack the auth-guard to access the page by inspecting the browser window, since typescript gets transpilled to javascript or is the auth-guard server sided by any chance.

Comment: An auth guard is not really a security measure. Nothing will ever prevent anyone from sending fake http requests to your server. So security needs to be at server side. But an auth guard is an easy and central way to redirect users to a login page if they're not logged in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client-side.

It depends. The framework (angular) has encryptors, code minifiers, and other validators that make it a little difficult for hackers, but it's still not completely secure.

There are some people who put validation variables in the localStorage and that is horrible. Others, put global variables in some service file. Which is also very insecure.

The best way is to create a service to validate on the Back-end side.

Answer (score 2):

"Never trust the client" - 
Someone correct me, but Angular is only client sided. 
Guards are here to help you implements your security, mostly with JSON Web Token in case of an API.

You should always have a security on server side. This case isn't an exception.

If you don't check on server side, anyone will be able to perform http request and get a 200 (sucess).

Answer (score 0):

Guard is a convenient way for you to organize your UI logic: show/hide certain parts (possibly, among other things, based on user permissions as gotten from server). Also, they can preload data needed for some component to work.

When it comes to security, guards can of course be overriden rather easily. For that reason, as someone already mentioned, 'never trust the client' and your server should implement actual access policy and permissions check based on cookie, token or whatever authentication/authorization mechanism you use.